# How to have different launch screens for different schemes?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using:

- Swift 5
- Xcode 12
- Different schemes for different purposes.

I am looking for a way to have a different LaunchScreen depending of the schemes built.

From the Targets->General->App Icons and Launch Images, I don't see any flexibility to choose a different file for different schemes. I thought by using the same file name in my different image assets would do the trick, but it looks like the launch screen is something independant form the whole app.

From the Targets->Build Settings, there is "Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name", but don't know what exactly I need to put there and if it really change something for the launch screen.

I also tried to change, in my info.plist files, the "Launch screen interface file base name", but does not seem to do anything. Maybe I forgot to do something else to make it work though.

If possible, any suggestions to solve that issue?

Thanks

Comment: Launch screen is set by target, not scheme.

Comment: thanks @matt for the answer

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but it's possible to do this using the following way:

1. Create a Storyboard for each of the launch screen e.g `LaunchStaging.storyboard, LaunchProduction.storyboard`
2. For each of the Storyboard, ensure that the setting under `Attributes inspector` **Is Initial View Controller** is checked
3. Also, ensure that the setting under `File inspector` **Use as Launch Screen** is checked
4. Under the xcode project's target, go into `Build Settings`
5. Add a new **User-Defined Setting** e.g `LAUNCH_SCREEN`
6. From the newly added setting, set the corresponding Storyboard's name as the value for each of the scheme, e.g `staging => LaunchStaging, production => LaunchProduction`
7. Inside `Info.plist`, under **Launch screen interface file base name**, set the value as **$(LAUNCH_SCREEN)**

This should allow you to have different launch screens for different schemes